# Vba - importing formcontrol combo box result in to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, form-control

Firstly I have tried googling this and made countless attempts to get it to work but can't Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Drop down is being used to populate a vba auto issued email

Code as below

```
Public sub Template

Dim olkApp As Object
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strAtt As String

StrSubject = "Transfer Please"
StrBody = "general text" & (here is where I need the 
selected dropdown imputed)
StrTo = (here I need the selected drop downs adjacent 
 referenced cell)
Strcc = ""
StrAtt = ""

Set olkApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
With olkApp.createitem(0)
 .To = strTo
.Cc = strCc
.Subject = strSubject
.body = strBody
.Display
End With
Set olk = Nothing
MsgBox "Email Issued"
End Sub
```

On my latest attempt I have tried using

```
Dim TOffice As String

With worksheets("Sheet7").Shapes("ToBox).ControlFormat
TOffice = .List(.ListIndex)
End With
```

Then referencing TOffice within StrBody

Q1 would I be better using User Form over FormControl
Q2 how do I reference a form control dropdown selected value within the strbody text.

I hope this is clear enough

Update
ok everything is working thank you. But I have 1 last question, StrTo is an email address that is listed beside the list that is used for a combo box how do I retrieve the adjacent cells information from the selected item in the dropdown?
I have used

```
Dim Cb As Object, Str As String
Set CB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ToBox").OLEFormat.Object
Str = Cb.ListFillRange
Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1") = Str
End Sub
```

This returns Sheet2!C2:C36
How do I use this to get the selected drop down and then change that to d instead of c

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your form control and select "Format Control". Under the Control tab, set the Cell Link property to the address of the cell under the control. This will then be automatically populated with the listindex of the selected item in the combo - so if you select the first item it will hold 1, if you select the fifth is will hold five. You can then refer to that cell to find what had been selected

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I get what your saying but when I right click and and select Format control... I only get the following tabs size,Protection,Properties,Alt text ... no control tab. I'm new to using form controls should I be using Activex for this is that the issue?

Comment: Lol i have found the LinkedCell under properties doing as you have said cheers